# Сравнить объекты внутри одного массива и объединить их значения

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты, объединение

Подскажите как решить данную проблему:

Есть массив объектов:

```
let family = [{'name':'apple', 'delivery_time': '11:00', 'prise':'100'}, 
               {'name':'pear', 'delivery_time': '12:00', 'prise':'100'}, 
               {'name':'melon', 'delivery_time': '13:00', 'prise':'100'}, 
               {'name':'apple', 'delivery_time': '11:00', 'prise':'100'}];
```

Как внутри этого массива узнать, есть ли повторные значения (в данном примере это `apple`), и дальше создать новый массив объектов, куда записать все уникальные значение, а также оставить только один `apple` с объединенной ценой `200`, чтобы получилось так:

```
 let family_two = [{'name':'apple', 'delivery_time': '11:00', 'prise':'200'}, 
               {'name':'pear', 'delivery_time': '12:00', 'prise':'100'}, 
               {'name':'melon', 'delivery_time': '13:00', 'prise':'100'}];
```

Пробовал делать это в цикле на сам массив, типа

```
for (var ii = 0; ii < family .length; ii++) {}
```

но получаются все значения сравниваются сами с собой.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, логику кода или пример функции, чтобы решить данную задачу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так хотели?

```js
let family = [{'name':'apple', 'delivery_time': '11:00', 'prise':'100'}, 
               {'name':'pear', 'delivery_time': '12:00', 'prise':'100'}, 
               {'name':'melon', 'delivery_time': '13:00', 'prise':'100'}, 
               {'name':'apple', 'delivery_time': '11:00', 'prise':'100'}];
               
  let result = family.reduce((acc, item) => { 
  let oldItem = acc.find(oldItem => oldItem.name === item.name);
  if (oldItem) {
        oldItem.prise = ""+((+oldItem.prise)+(+item.prise))} 
  else {
        acc.push(item) 
   }
   return acc;
  }, 
  []);
  
  console.log(result);
```

объекты сравниваются по полям

```
acc.find(oldItem => oldItem.name === item.name)
```

По логике. Пробегаемся по массиву готовим результирующий набор. Если элемент существует в наборе то прибавляем значения если нет то добавляем сам элемент в результирующий набор.

или тоже самое в ручной минификации. (только ради забавы)

```js
let family = [{'name':'apple', 'delivery_time': '11:00', 'prise':'100'}, 
               {'name':'pear', 'delivery_time': '12:00', 'prise':'100'}, 
               {'name':'melon', 'delivery_time': '13:00', 'prise':'100'}, 
               {'name':'apple', 'delivery_time': '11:00', 'prise':'100'}];
let result = family.reduce((a, i) => {let o=a.find(o=>o.name==i.name);o&&(o.prise=""+((+o.prise)+(+i.prise)))||a.push(i);return a},[]);
  
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Спасибо! То, что надо!!!